# setNativeProps({step: num}) on SliderIOS does not work in React Native

Tags: react-native

My example is straightforward. I'm properly assigning the reference to the slider and then trying to set its native *step* prop:

```
<SliderIOS
  ref={(slider) => this.slider = slider}
  onValueChange={(value) {
     if(value >= 1000) this.slider.setNativeProps({step: 100});
     else this.slider.setNativeProps({step: 100});
  }}
```

but I get the error:

"react native cannot read property 'validAttributes' of undefined"

The slider is defined. I've logged it to the console, and it has the `setNativeProps` method, etc. The error is happening later in the react native code.

Answer (score 0):

I had met this problem yesterday.
When I used the `refreshControl` in `ListView` , I caught a error 
 **Cannot read property 'validAttributes' of undefined**

This is my code

```
 
    <ListView      
     dataSource={theDataSource}
     renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
     onEndReached={this.props.pullUp.bind(this)}
     refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          ref='freshIndicator'
          refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
          onRefresh={()=>this._onRefresh()}
          title={this.state.freshText}
          titleColor={Util.themeColor}
          tintColor={Util.themeColor}/>
          }
    />
```

```
_onRefresh(){
    console.log(this.refs['freshIndicator']);
    this.refs['freshIndicator']._nativeRef.setNativeProps({
      refreshing: true,
      title:'loading'
    });
    this.props.onRefresh();}
```

Do not use `setNativeProps` like this component ,otherwise use `this.refs['freshIndicator']._nativeRef.setNativeProps` instead.

attention the `_nativeRef` property

The refreshing works fine.